# Transform large pd.Series into a DataFrame of n columns

Tags: dataset, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `pd.Series` with, for instance, `n` lines. I would like to transform this series in a `pd.DataFrame` as follows:

Ex:

Input: `pd.Series([10,11,12,13,14,15])` and a variable `chunk_size = 2` that will be the number of columns.

Target:

```
    0 | 1
    _   _
    10  11
    12  13
    14  15
```

The target DataFrame will have a shape of `(n / chunk_size)` rows by `chunk_size` columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution that does not do it in-place but takes up extra space:

```
def transform_series(x, chunk_size):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(chunk_size):
        df[f'column_{i+1}'] = x[i::chunk_size].reset_index(drop=True)
    return df


input_series = pd.Series([10,11,12,13,14,15])
transformed_df = transform_series(input_series, chunk_size=2)
```

Output:

```
print(transformed_df)

   column_1  column_2
0        10        11
1        12        13
2        14        15
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. Please run your code with the same input but with chunk_size=4. Why some columns are Float and others Int?

Comment: If you ran it on the same input with 6 values it will not be able to split it into 4 columns while populating all the cells. You need `len(input_series) % chunk_size = 0` in order to populate all values. The columns are `float64` because the last two column will contain `NaN`s because it doesn't have enough values in the series to fill the whole matrix.

Comment: Got it. Since i will be working mostly with float values, this won't be a problem. Thanks!